# How to get labels on top of bars in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want a barchart with labels on top of the bars, showing a group of bars, with errors, and labels on top of the bars indicating how much this bar differs from the first one. Although i get the positioning about right, it is always a little off. Y seems to be correct, even with large errors, but the x position is only absolutely correct on the middle bar (blue C), all bars left seem a little too much left, and all on the right a little too much right. Additionally, the more bars there are, the bigger the unwanted offset gets. Is there an error in my position computation? Is there a better way to do this?

I use this piece of code to position the labels:

```
with labels center offset first (1 + (i - (configurations-1) / 2.0) / (configurations))
```

I'm posting an example script and datafile as well as the resulting plot showing the plot here: (the code in the end of the second for loop controls the position of the labels:

The plot:
[image]

The script test.gnuplot:

```
reset
set terminal png size 500,300
set autoscale
set yrange [0:]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1 errorbars
set style fill solid border -1
set key inside right top vertical 
set key autotitle columnheader 
set boxwidth 0.9
configurations=5
plot for[i=0:(configurations-1):1] 'test.data' using 2+i*3:2+i*3+1:2+i*3+2:xtic(1) title col, for[i=1:(configurations-1):1] '' using ($0 - 1):2+i*3+2:(gprintf("%+-.0f%%", (column(2+i*3+0)/column(2+0*3+0)-1) * 100)) with labels center offset first (1 + (i - (configurations-1) / 2.0) / (configurations)), character 0.5 notitle
quit
```

The data file test.data:

```
"" A A A B B B C C C D D D E E E
"Foo" 5.8058873543 5.7058873543 5.9058873543 5.6901595056 5.3101595056 6.2901595056 8.09519137 8.00519137 8.10519137 7.3446561007 7.2446561007 7.4446561007 9.2118493572 9.0118493572 9.3118493572
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxwidth, and therefore also the position of each box is given by the number of `configurations` plus the size of the gap between two clusters, in your case `1`. And, instead of putting the x-position in the `offset` parameter, you can as well move it to the `using` statement. Use `set xrange` to restrict the gaps on the left and right side:

```
set style histogram cluster gap 1 errorbars
set style fill solid border -1
set key inside right top vertical 
set key autotitle columnheader 
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
configurations=5
set xrange [-0.5:0.7]
plot for[i=0:(configurations-1):1] 'test.data' using 2+i*3:2+i*3+1:2+i*3+2:xtic(1) title col, \
     for[i=1:(configurations-1):1] '' using ((i - (configurations-1) / 2.0) / (configurations + 1)):2+i*3+2:(gprintf("%+-.0f%%", (column(2+i*3+0)/column(2+0*3+0)-1) * 100)) with labels center offset 0, character 0.5 notitle
```

[image]